# PyQt: Trying to display SQLite DB in QTableView: 'argument 1 has unexpected type 'PyQt4.QtCore.pyqtWrapperType'

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt4

Ok, I fixed it, make sure to call the class with Model()

However, the below code does not work, and results in segfault for some reason. I fixed it by putting the DB and model stuff directly into the main GUI class.

I have a Ui element called table, and following code:

```
import sqlite3

from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtSql
from PyQt4.Qt import *

from ui.mainWindow import *


class Database(QtSql.QSqlDatabase) :
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Database,  self).__init__(parent)
        self.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
        self.setDatabaseName('/db/daily.sql')
        self.open()

class Model(QtSql.QSqlTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, db=Database()):
        super(Model, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setTable('body')
        self.select()

class Gui(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.tableModel = Model()

        self.ui.table.setModel(self.tableModel)
        self.ui.table.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = Gui()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And get the following error:

TypeError: QTableView.setModel(QAbstractItemModel): argument 1 has unexpected type 'PyQt4.QtCore.pyqtWrapperType'

If I set up the Database and Model directly in the Gui class, the program starts, but the table is empty (DB is populated).

What causes this error?

Comment: Line: `self.tableModel = Model` should be `self.TableModel = Model()` because you are calling a class.

Comment: Ah yes, always the simple stuff that gets you. It loads, table is still empty however.

Comment: what does it print if you change your Database class line: `self.open()` to `print(self.open())`?

Comment: Well the DB class didnt get called, I fixed that, now I get a segfault, although the database is very small (90 entries). Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you have so far.

Comment: I did, its basically the same, just changed def __init__(self, parent = None, db=Database): to def __init__(self, parent = None, db=Database()):